# Jmeter post processor and while controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a post -processor with the below code.

```
import test.MFG
MFG mfgRepo = new MFG();
log.info("device {}","${deviceID}");
long crashTime= ${p1};
String deviceId1="${deviceID}";
log.info("the crashtime is {}",crashTime);

List<Map<String,Object>> dbItem = mfgRepo.getItemFromDB("TEST",deviceId1,crashTime);
log.info("The item is {}",dbItem.get(0).get("info"));
```

In the above the deviceID and p1 are variables that vary in each request e.g testdevice1,testdevice2... and p1 is a different timestamp. when these values are run in a postprocessor only the first request value is been processed in all the post-processor. what am I doing wrong?
how can I implement the same validation in a while controller which would go and test if dbItem.get(0).get("info") is not null for each request made in a concurrency thread group.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code **as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So change your:

- `${deviceID}"` to `vars.get('deviceID')`
- `${p1}` to `vars.get('p1') as long`
- etc.

where `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for full description of available functions and properties and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on using this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: how to implement the above in the while controller so that I can validate the item is in DB.